# Можно ли узнать запущена ли Coroutine Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно узнать запущена ли StartCoroutine? что бы в Update не вызвать её снова.

Comment: Вообще любую? Запущена ли хоть какая-то корутина? Или одну конкретную отследить?

Comment: Определенную допустим StartCoroutine(RestoringTheHp()); вот такую запустил и вот на последующий кадр узнать запущена ли она.

Comment: Вообще, если это, так сказать, разовая акция)) (для одной корутины, а не для десятка), то сойдёт установка булевого флага во время старта корутины и во время её завершения https://answers.unity.com/questions/126783/can-i-check-if-a-coroutine-is-running.html

Comment: Спасибо большое, а вот если, проверить запущена ли хоть какая корутина?

Comment: Наверное при запуске в счётчик прибавлять и при окончании убавлять........ ещё есть вариант отслеживания состояния корутин в виде такого скрипта : https://forum.unity.com/threads/a-more-flexible-coroutine-interface.94220/   при таком раскладе вообще можно при запуске корутин складывать их в список. и с ним делать что угодно. пробежался - нашёл нужную и проверил состояние....пробежался, если хотя бы у одного состояние  `Running` - то есть работающие корутины........... в целом, конечно, ещё от кода зависит что нужно и где)) может вам вообще вся инфа о корутинах и не нужна))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сама Unity не предоставляет такую возможность, но можно написать костыль:

```
bool start = false;

void Update (){
if(!start){
StartCoroutine(RestoringTheHp()); 
}
```

Далее, в начале корутины, поставьте:
`start = true;`, а в конце: `start = false`